# Traer datos de un JSON a un archivo JS (ubicados en el mismo directorio)

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

¡Hola a todos!

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: Proyecto]

En mi JSON tengo algo como lo siguiente:

```
{
    "myQuestions": [
        ["Llave", "Tela", "Lavamanos", "Hojilla"],
        ["Caracol", "Almendra", "Estrella", "Toalla"],
        ["Triangulo", "Cuadrado", "Rectángulo", "Caramelo"] 
    ]
}
```

Y necesito traer los datos que necesito desde este JSON a mi archivo JS para poder acceder a ellos y utilizarlos.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Siento mucho si la pregunta es muy simple, pero no encuentro una forma de hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Edición 1 (en respuesta a Eugeni):

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let res = this.responseText;
            let converRes = JSON.parse(res);
        }
    };

xhttp.open("GET", "questions.json", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

Sí, estoy usando Liveserver.

Comment: En que contexto trabajas con javascript? Es decir en el lado del cliente(navegador) o en el servidor. Depende del uno u otro se hace de manera diferente.

Comment: Hola, Eugeni. Ahora mismo en el lado del cliente, pero no descarto realizar un procedimiento parecido en el futuro en el lado del servidor. Así que si pudieses darme ambas soluciones te lo agradecería.

Comment: Podrías añadir el código que has intentado? Ya tienes un servidor que te sirve tus archivos(html, js, css y etc)

Comment: En el post inicial dejé el código que intenté, pero no funcionó. Recibo un error 404 (Not Found).

Comment: Comentario al margen: ten en cuenta que la imagen que subiste es prácticamente ilegible en el modo oscuro, por lo tanto, podrías nada más agregar como texto la estructura de tu proyecto.

Comment: He visto que has marcado como correcta mi respuesta y luego lo has quitado, ¿Se debe a algo?

Comment: Ya lo arreglé, tuve una pequeña confusión con los íconos de las flechas y el icono de "Respuesta aceptada". Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como has comentado antes, el escenario este en la parte del navegador, entonces aquí hay que tener una cosa en cuenta, y es que el archivo debe ser accesible desde una `URL`, por ejemplo `http://localhost:8080/questions.json` ya que por defecto javascript no tiene manera de leer los archivos(en el navegador)

Dicho esto, imaginemos que la URL del archivo que queremos recuperar es la siguiente.

> http://localhost:8080/questions.json

Entonces en nuestro archivo `main.js` deberíamos de escribir una funciona tipo así,

```
function fetchQuestions(){
    // Si el archivo esta en el mismo servidor, 
    // podemos simplemente poner el path, ej: /static/questions.json
    // Y si esta en un servidor externo, 
    // deberíamos de poner la URL completa, ej: 
    // https://domain.com/static/questions.json, puede que tengas problemas de cors

    fetch('/questions.json') //Como estamos en el mismo servidor
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

Ahora simplemente te quedaría llamar a la función y obtendrás el contenido del archivo `.json`

Bien, para hacerlo desde el servidor y enviar ese `JSON`, podríamos el modulo [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) que nos permite leer el contenido de un archivo(entre otras más cosas), por ejemplo(siguiendo la estructura de tu proyecto).

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('./questions', function(err, data){
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("El contenido es: ", JSON.parse(data))
})
```

> Recomiendo usar `fetch` ya que es muy mas moderno y mas simple, y es [compatible](https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch) con casi todos los navegadores